# Finding Rows based on a set of same columns in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider following table:-

```
-----------------------------------------
  ID      TEACHER    SUBJECT     GRADE
-----------------------------------------
  1        Jack       Physics      8
  2        Paul       Chemistry    10
  3        Susan      English      6
  4        Jack       Maths        8
  5        Jack       Physics     10
  6        Paul       Chemistry   10
```

---

i want to identify the rows with same values for TEACHER and SUBJECT columns. irrespective of values in ID and GRADE columns. The following rows thus will be identified:-

```
 -------------------------------------
  ID      TEACHER     SUBJECT   GRADE
 -------------------------------------
  1        Jack       Physics      8
  2        Paul       Chemistry    10
  5        Jack       Physics     10
  6        Paul       Chemistry   10
 -------------------------------------
```

how to achieve such a result in oracle sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT null FROM Table1 t2
  WHERE t1."TEACHER" = t2."TEACHER"
    AND t1."SUBJECT" = t2."SUBJECT"
    AND t1."ID" <> t2."ID"
)
ORDER BY "ID"
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3d2bd4/3

Comment: Test this solution where there are more than 2 rows of the same combination in your table it will NOT restrict the output to just the distinct combinations. e.g. see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4bcd5/1

Comment: @Used_By_Already I've read carefully the question a few times, but can't find a requirement to display **distinct combinations**, but only to **identify the rows with same values**

Comment: Well we disagree. My reading of the question is that `i want to identify the rows with same values for TEACHER and SUBJECT columns` = distinct. Then `irrespective of values in ID and GRADE` means as long as the uniqueness of TEACHER and SUBJECT exists, just provide whatever value you can for those other 2 columns. I may indeed be wrong, but it is how I interpret the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below select:

```
SELECT 
      a.* 
  FROM (SELECT 
             COUNT(1) cnt,
             teacher,
             subject 
         FROM your_table
         GROUP BY teacher,subject
         HAVING COUNT(1) > 1)rec,
Your_table a
WHERE a.teacher=rec.teacher AND a.subject=rec.subject
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ROW_NUMBER()` will provide a simple method of choosing just one row for the unique combinations of teacher and subject but I haven't exactly matched the results provided by the question. However using `ROW_NUMBER()` enables a logic where you can choose which other field(s) will determine which of the rows is returned:

```
SELECT 
       id, teacher, subject, grade 
FROM (
      SELECT
           id, teacher, subject, grade 
         , row_number() over(partition by teacher, subject ORDER BY id ASC) as RN
      FROM Table1
      )
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY teacher, subject ;
```

Using ascending order of ID the result is:

```
| ID | TEACHER |   SUBJECT | GRADE |
|----|---------|-----------|-------|
|  4 |    Jack |     Maths |     8 |
|  1 |    Jack |   Physics |     8 |
|  2 |    Paul | Chemistry |    10 |
|  3 |   Susan |   English |     6 |
```

or simply by changing the order to:  **grade DESC**

```
| ID | TEACHER |   SUBJECT | GRADE |
|----|---------|-----------|-------|
|  4 |    Jack |     Maths |     8 |
|  5 |    Jack |   Physics |    10 |
|  2 |    Paul | Chemistry |    10 |
|  3 |   Susan |   English |     6 |
```

Often this technique is used to get the `most recent` or `oldest` rows (based on some date/time data) for another example of how it can be used.

<kbd>[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d81eb/2)</kbd>